# Laravel 5.0 Intervention Image

Tags: laravel-5, intervention

> Class `Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class` not found

I have installed this package using composer and update providers and facaded also. Still this error has shown.

Comment: Make sure you run `composer dump-autoload`, that will update the autoload files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

add this in your project

In **config=>app=>providers**

```
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,
```

In **config=>app=>aliases**

```
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,
```

In your **controller**

```
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have got solution by changing inside autoload_ps4.php

Comment: that would be great